# Looking for story of Erekosë

Tags: story-identification, eternal-champion

I've read two stories featuring this character, but both from the perspective of other incarnations of the Eternal Champion: Elric's in *The Vanishing Tower* and the other from Prince Corum's (though my memory of the latter is vague). If Moorcock wrote Erekosë's story from his own point of view, what was it titled?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erekos%C3%AB

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81794/novel-where-man-wakes-up-in-a-random-time-period-find-his-services-as-a-soldier (about the series)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### There is no single story where Erekosë appears where we are aware of his travels to the Vanishing Tower. Moorcock was not always consistent with the comings and goings of the Eternal Champion. Indeed in many cases, when the Champion becomes aware of a conjunction or opportunity to meet his other selves once the Champion returned to his place in the time stream, even he may not be aware it has happened.

Erekosë's primary appearances are in the [Eternal Champion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Eternal_Champion_(novel)), [Phoenix in Obsidian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_in_Obsidian) and the [Dragon in the Sword](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/757283.The_Dragon_in_the_Sword). We are never privy to a moment where he appears in the Vanishing Tower.

- This are the first singular appearances we see Erekosë appearing in and even then he is timelost, appearing in the bodies of other Eternal Champions fighting their struggles more effectively due to his differing perspectives.

> - Erekosë, Urlik, Clen, Flamadin and Daker are related incarnations of the Eternal Champion, in that the individual transforms over the course of several novels while maintaining the memories of each and is not biologically reborn between each aspect. He remembers the lives of numerous other incarnations, the third identity assumed by John Daker.

Comment: The Vanishing Tower incident referred to in the question doesn't appear in any of those three books.  To the best of my knowledge, you never experience it from Erekose's own perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Although the narrative is initially framed through the character of John Daker, [The Eternal Champion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Eternal_Champion_(novel)) takes place primarily from the viewpoint of Erekose.